Why is one of my cats suddenly harassing one of my other cats?
I have two male cats who are both five years old and neutered. I got Kobe when he was three months old and when he turned 5 months I adopted another cat and named him Jordan.
For the most part they live harmoniously up until about 2 months ago.
For example: They’re both napping, Kobe will wake up first and while Jordan is sleeping it tries to climb on top of him and bite the back of his neck. Usually Jordan will move away or sometimes he may raise a paw and smack him.
Usually when he does this I will chase him off but now it’s getting excessive. It’s almost like he waits until I leave the room and does it too.
Does anyone know why he does this? Does he not like his brother anymore?

Are your cats sexually intact or neutered? Please click [edit] to add this information to your question.

I highly doubt this is related to cats not liking each other. Cats who get along almost always keep getting along unless something changes.
Firstly, as Elmy commented, whether the cats are neutered is of paramount importance. Neutering takes away most of the aggression. Now, I will assume they are neutered as intact male cats rarely get along for five years without drawing some blood at one point.
At the first glance, it looks like they are playing, a bit rougher than they normally do. Unless one of them draws blood, it might not be of significant importance. Still, it is helpful to look into it, before they draw blood.
Cats tend to exhibit behavioural changes if some dynamic in their lives changes. Some of the dynamics to look into are

Moving houses,
Changing/reduction of the food
A new source of sound/smell, like a neighbour getting a pet, or a new store opening in the neighbourhood
Getting a new job such that you are at home at different hours than the usual,
Getting a new flatmate/partner
Buying a new piece of furniture or removing an old piece furniture

I would start analysing what might have changed two months ago. If you can pinpoint to some change, you can either try to fix it, i.e., like rearranging the furniture back to their original places, or wait for your cats to get used to this new dynamic. However, since your cats get friskier, there is a chance they might not get used this new dynamic.
If you cannot find any recent change, I would suggest a vet visit. Behavioural changes can also be indicative of an underlying condition. I am not a vet so I cannot suggest anything further, but I believe even a simple blood work might be enough to ease your mind.
Meanwhile, it is possible to alleviate Jordan's suffering. You can get a cat house at a slightly elevated location with one entrance, something like this without the cat tree on the left. Either Kobe will claim it for himself and leave Jordan alone, or Jordan can go and nap there where Kobe cannot easily jump on him. When something similar happened to my friends' cats, we took advantage of the aggressive cat being overweight to jump high locations and installed something similar on top of the shelves, where only the other cat can reach.
I hope this helps.
